# Anchor identification for custom shelving

Tags: screws, shelving, bolts, anchor, hardware

Rookie hardware question: my father built our kids some custom shelves and gave me several sets of these wall anchors/bolts to install them. I know this is a wall anchor system but looks significantly different than anything I've ever bought from big box stores before:

[image]

What are these called (**specifically**) so I can Google them and figure out how to use them for the shelving installation?

Comment: Screw in drywall anchors.  I do prefer to use studs to hang stuff on walls.  Drywall is good for holding paint/posters on.  Studs are good to hold stuff you care about.

Comment: Might not apply in your case, but studs are always better than drywall for attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [drywall anchors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09H38ZYDD)  You screw the white plastic part into the wall (drywall) where you want to have a screw, but there is no stud.

Attach the screw through a hole in whatever you wish to mount to the wall and into the plastic "anchor" you installed into the wall.

They come in various sizes and can hold various weight, based on size.

Comment: As noted in the comments on the OP, despite the various weight bearing capacity claimed by the manufacturers, the preferred option is to attach things like shelving directly to studs. Especially where active children are involved. Kids tend to do things they shouldn't (like climbing on shelves) and you want the most assurance possible that the shelves won't fall over on the kid. _I_ consider some screws into studs and some into anchors (if alignment with studs everywhere isn't possible) to be an acceptable option. Others may disagree with me.